# Is it possible to open a terminal session to ebs linux instance?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Linux elastic beanstalk app running on aws.  I need to figure out what folders the apps are installed in order to create a cronjob correctly.

Is it possible to open a terminal to ebs server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. To SSH to the Elastic Beanstalk Instance, you will need to use the EC2 key pairs and configure the Security Groups allowing SSH access from the client.

If you place the server in a private subnet, you might need to create a Bastion Host in a public subnet within the same VPC. Then you can SSH to the Bastion host and SSH to your sever from there.